# Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin Android compile warning "fakeLogOpen(/dev/log_security) failed" breaks build

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to compile an Android app written in **C#**,
using **Visual Studio 2017** (and **Xamarin**), on **Windows**.

Whenever I try to compile the project and deploy it to
the android emulator, I keep receiving this **WARNING**: "**fakeLogOpen(/dev/log_security) failed**".

There aren't details explaining the cause.

Why am I getting this error / warning?

Comment: Did you recently update to Visual Studio 15.6/15.6.1? I'm having this occur on one machine with 15.6.1 installed, but not on another with 15.5.7 installed. The project is the same in both cases.

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/210640/xamarin-android-fakelogopendevlog-crash-failed.html), by @Brendan Zagaeski [MSFT]'s comment.

Comment: We're also getting these warning messages since upgrading from VS 15.5.7 to 15.6.1. They don't seem to cause any problems so far besides being annoying. Hoping for a fix in the next version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems they fixed it for the next update:

> Jonathan Pryor
>
> Thank you for your feedback! We have fixed the problem in an upcoming
>   release. Thank you for helping us build a better Visual Studio!

See: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/210640/xamarin-android-fakelogopendevlog-crash-failed.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)